# Difference between _,frame and frame in Python

Tags: python, opencv

What is the difference between  _,frame  and frame in Python?

```
 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

 while(1):
     _, frame = cap.read()
     cv2.imshow('frame ',frame )
```

is working, but code

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

 while(1):
     frame = cap.read()
     cv2.imshow('frame ',frame )
```

is not working

Answer (score 5):

`cap.read()` is returning a tuple which is being unpacked into the two variables `_` and `frame`. `_` is just a way of stating that you are ignoring that value. It could have been written as:

```
ignored, frame = cap.read()
```

In the second case, the tuple is not unpacked because there is only one variable, and so the tuple is bound to `frame`. The tuple `frame` is then passed into `cv2.imshow()`, but this function doesn't expect to see a tuple in the second argument, hence the error that you are seeing.